# Set partitions and collections

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am looking over a practice exam having trouble remembering what exactly a collection is when referring to sets. Partitions are easier to grasp on the other hand. 
I am stuck on what the question is asking for part B and C. If anyone could explain where to start with those parts i would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Find one partition, S, and one collection T, of the set A={0,1,2,3,4,5,...} which satisfies all three of the following conditions:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2s1v.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection, also called a family, is a set of sets.  A partition $S$ of a set $A$ is a collection of sets such that each set is mutually disjoint (*have no elements in common*) and whose union is the set $A$ itself.

In this case, you have the set $A=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,\dots\}$ and you find a partition of $A$, we call the partition $S$.  We want $S$ to have three elements, i.e. we broke $A$ into three parts, e.g. $S=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2,3,4,5,\dots\}\}$  or $S=\{\{0,3,6,9,\dots\},\{1,4,7,\dots\},\{2,5,8,\dots\}\}$.

Those examples I gave will satisfy the first condition (*to break $A$ into three parts*), as well as the third condition (*to have no part of size two*), but not the second condition.  The second condition says that there need to be two of the parts with a total number of elements equal to four.

---

Worded a different way: Can you find a way to partition $\{0,1,2,3,4,\dots,\}$ into parts such that

- there are a total of three parts
- there are two of those parts whose combined total number of elements is equal to four
- no part is of size two

Comment: $S=\{ \{0\},\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6,...\}\}$.and $T=\{\{0\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.